# Python - Extrude vertices while filling them

Tags: python

I want to mimic a behaviour in Blender using Python. I Add a new plane, switch to Edit mode to only keep the vertices, then Vertex mode, select 2 or more neighbour vertices, then extrude them, the extrusion will create faces (like walls):
[image]

Using code, I'm able to Extrude the vertices, this creates the edges, but the faces are not filled :

```
import bpy

# Get the selected object
object = bpy.context.object

# Get the mesh...
mesh = object.data

bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode="EDIT") 

# Extude the vertices
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_vertices_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={"value": (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)})
```

Here is the result - I have new vertices but no faces :
[image]

Any tips ?

Comment: That's how extruding vertices works. It looks like you want to extrude edges: `bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_edges_move()`

Comment: So Blender kind of do something differently under the hood then. Makes sense. Thing is, I'm using vertex groups, so I have to select the edges based on them. Is there a way to select (already existing) edges made by a list of vertices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you used Geometry Nodes, it would perhaps be more obvious that there is a difference between extruding vertices, edges and faces:

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

The inconsistency you're perceiving comes from the fact that in the User Interface in Edit Mode, regardless of selection mode <kbd>1</kbd>/<kbd>2</kbd>/<kbd>3</kbd>, if all vertices of an edge are selected, that edge also becomes selected, and same goes for faces. It's not so clearly communicated in case of edges, because while they are highlighted, you may think it's just the sum of two gradient shadings that are supposed to help seeing selected vertices:

[image]

But in case of faces it's communicated clearly, once all vertices of a face are selected, the face also becomes selected:

[image]

The only way to select vertices without edges and faces, that I know of, is using `bmesh`:

[image]

(Which is even called an "invalid selection state", though I'm not sure if selecting all vertices of a face is an invalid state, the [documentation](https://docs.blender.org/api/current/bmesh.html#selection-flushing) says selecting a face without its vertices is "invalid")

So if You use `bmesh`, then you need to also use `bm.select_flush()` after selecting your vertices. But since you don't use `bmesh`, all you have to do, is to replace your function `bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_vertices_move()` with `bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_edges_move()`:

```py
import bpy
from bpy import context as C

ob = C.object
me = ob.data
vertex_group_index = ob.vertex_groups['Group'].index
for v in me.vertices:
    v.select = any(g.group == vertex_group_index for g in v.groups)
bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode='EDIT')
bpy.ops.mesh.extrude_edges_move(TRANSFORM_OT_translate={'value': (0.0, 0.0, 1.0)})
```

Comment: Incredible answer, it's very detailled. Thanks! I did think I had to have edges selected to do an edge extrude, but it seems not!

Comment: @Beb You had to have edges selected, and you had edges selected, that's the point. Cheers!